# PHP reflection and invokeArgs(): forcing a parameter to use its default value

Tags: php, reflection, parameters

I need to call a function using the Reflection API. The function has optional parameters, and I need to invoke it providing just some of them.

For example, I have this function:

```
public function doSomething($firstParam, $secondParam = "default", $thirdParam = "default)
```

And I'm using `invokeArgs()` to invoke `doSomething()`, passing an array of values representing the arguments omitting to set a value to the optional `$secondParam`:

```
$parameters = array("firstParam"=>"value", "thirdParam"=>"thirdValue");
$reflectedDoSomething->invokeArgs($instance, $parameters);
```

What happens here is that `invokeArgs()` invokes the method setting its parameters in a row, without skipping the `$secondParam`, that now is valued "thirdValue" and omitting the `$thirdParam`. And that's logically correct. The method is invoked like `doSomething("value", "thirdValue")`.

What I'd like to do here is to force the `$secondParam` to use its default value. Setting `"secondParam" => null` in the `$parameters` array is not a solution because `null` is a value.

Is it possibile using Reflection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the first comment on [the docs for `invokeArgs()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php#100041).

So, just run the params through a simple algorithm (you could create a function for wrapping this if you wanted to):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionMethod($obj, $method); 

$pass = array(); 
foreach($reflection->getParameters() as $param) { 
   /* @var $param ReflectionParameter */ 
   if(isset($args[$param->getName()])) { 
       $pass[] = $args[$param->getName()]; 
   } else { 
       $pass[] = $param->getDefaultValue(); 
   } 
} 
$reflection->invokeArgs($obj, $pass);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about not setting the associative name `secondParam`, but rather putting a `null` as a second second parameter.

```
$parameters = array("firstParam"=>"value", null, "thirdParam"=>"thirdValue");
```